# neo4j cypher compare chain of nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Given a text in a graph-db with the words as nodes:

```
... (:word {text:'Die'})-[:NEXT]->(:word {text:'Natur'})-[:NEXT]->(:word {text:'selbst'})-[:NEXT]->(:word {text:'ist'})-[:NEXT]->(:word {text:'Einheit'})-[:NEXT]->(:word {text:'in'})-[:NEXT]->(:word {text:'der'})-[:NEXT]->(:word {text:'Vielheit'}) ...
```

Now i want to find parts of the chain where the words:

```
(Natur), (Einheit) and (Vielheit)
```

occur within a range of max. 10 word-nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this...

```
// look for paths from two to nine relationships in length 
MATCH p=(n:Node)-[:NEXT*2..9]->(:Node) 

// find paths that have all of the words
WHERE ALL(label in ['Natur','Einheit','Vielheit'] where label in 
extract(node in nodes(p) | node.name ))

// return the nodes of the matching paths
RETURN nodes(p)
```

This is a superior approach. Be sure and and an index on `:Word(test)`.

```
// list of words
WITH ['Natur','Einheit','Vielheit'] AS texts

// find paths that include three words
MATCH path=(word1:Word )-[:NEXT*1..8]->(word2:Node)-[:NEXT*1..8]->(word3:Node)

// where each word is in your list
WHERE word1.text in texts
AND word2.text in texts
AND word3.text in texts

// and none of the words are the same
AND word1.text <> word2.text
AND word2.text <> word3.text
RETURN path
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I clarified the question. The nodes are of type word and the word are in the property text.